# UnicodeDecodeError during release upgrade (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS > 16.04 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, server, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

There is an Ubuntu 14.04.05 LTS Server-VM which has to be upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS. Unfortunately, I get the following error during the dist-upgrade:

```
  **File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-4b8li6el/DistUpgrade
/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 806, in installedTasks
for line in pkg._pcache._records.record.split("\n"):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position
337: invalid start byte**
```

**A workaround in the bug tracker, but it did not work for me:**
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager-core/+bug/1453740

**Other tipps that did not work:**

```
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8 LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=de_DE.UTF-8  
LC_ALL=de_DE.iso-8859-1 LANG=de_DE.iso-8859-1 LANGUAGE=de_DE.iso-8859-1
```

**Here are the commands I used for the upgrade:**

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core  
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

**The logs from screenlog:**
https://pastebin.com/SeWB5E9y